# Can't update npm packages: ERR! code EEXIST

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I'm trying to to upgrade npm packages via

```
npm update -g
```

But, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm: is outside C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

I've googled but none of the solutions work. One said to remove the npm.cmd and npm files from here:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

I tried that, but it fails as npm is now missing.

That folder, C:\Program Files\nodejs, is actually a shortcut pointing to

```
C:\Users\lthurman\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.1
```

I'm using nvm to manage my node installations, any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try doing this below command after deleting the folder `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm`, `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score 34):

**To resolve this issue I took the following steps**

> Where [userName] is your Windows user name -- [nodeVer] is your current version of Node, or the one that is giving you issues using NVM

Delete these four files:

```
C:\Users\[userName]\AppData\Roaming\nvm\[nodeVer]\npm
C:\Users\[userName]\AppData\Roaming\nvm\[nodeVer]\npm.cmd
C:\Users\[userName]\AppData\Roaming\nvm\[nodeVer]\npx
C:\Users\[userName]\AppData\Roaming\nvm\[nodeVer]\npx.cmd
```

Then in `C:\Users\[userName]\AppData\Roaming\nvm\[nodeVer]\node_modules\`, rename the `npm` directory to `npm_old`

Open up your console of choice -- run as admin if necessary -- and navigate into the `\npm_old\bin` directory then install NPM at latest (or replace latest w/a version of your choosing) using the command below:

```
node npm-cli.js i -g npm@latest
```

Clean-up by deleting the `npm_old` directory from earlier.  Now all should be good to go...I hope!

Comment: It works in my case with `nvm` on Windows. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I get the ''The term 'npm' is recognized... " error after deleting the above mentioned files.

Comment: You will need to change the package name of the npm_old package json file to npm old as well.

Comment: Works for me, nvm 1.1.7, Windows 10 build, 19041.1110

Comment: Thank you! save my day!

Comment: Oh man thank you so so much. I never would have thought of such a clever solution. You saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

It will fixed it by forcing the install with `--force`

```php
npm install -g npm@latest --force
```

Uninstall old version first

```
npm uninstall -g your-package-name
```

install the latest

```
npm install -g your-package-name@latest
```